# Generate a valid ES256 signature in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, jwt, mapkit, cxf

I'm trying to integrate Apple Map Web Snapshot which needs a signature query parameter in the URL. I able to successfully generate and validate ES256 signature in JWA package from NPM but not in Java. Please help me on finding equivalent lib to generate valid signature, I have tried few JWA libs in Java.

```
// Required modules.
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const { sign } = require("jwa")("ES256");

/* Read your private key from the file system. (Never add your private key
 * in code or in source control. Always keep it secure.)
 */ 
const privateKey = readFileSync("[file_system_path]");
// Replace the team ID and key ID values with your actual values.
const teamId = "[team ID]";
const keyId = "[key ID]";

// Creates the signature string and returns the full Snapshot request URL including the signature.
function sign(params) {
    const snapshotPath = `/api/v1/snapshot?${params}`;
    const completePath = `${snapshotPath}&teamId=${teamId}&keyId=${keyId}`;
    const signature = sign(completePath, privateKey);
    // In this example, the jwa module returns the signature as a Base64 URL-encoded string.

    // Append the signature to the end of the request URL, and return.
    return `${completePath}&signature=${signature}`;
}

// Call the sign function with a simple map request.
sign("center=apple+park") 

// The return value expected is: "/api/v1/snapshot?center=apple+park&teamId=[team ID]&keyId=[key ID]&signature=[base64_url_encoded_signature]"
```

Apache CXF - This lib generates similar to JWA module in node but failed to authenticate.

```
      String teamId = [Team Id];
       String keyId = [Key id];
       String privateKey = [private key path];

       String privateKeyContent = getKeyFileContent(privateKey);

       String API_VERSION_PATH = "/api/v1/snapshot?";

       String param = [QueryParam];

       //example -> param = "center=[city,country or lat,lang]&size=90x90&lang=en&radius=2";

       String params = param + "&teamId="+ teamId + "&keyId=" + keyId;

       String payload = API_VERSION_PATH + params;

       PrivateKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
               Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyContent)));

       JwsCompactProducer compactProducer = new JwsCompactProducer(payload);
       compactProducer.getJwsHeaders().setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256);
       //compactProducer.getJwsHeaders().setKeyId(keyId);


       compactProducer.signWith(key);

       String signed = compactProducer.getEncodedSignature();

       String encodedSignature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(compactProducer.getEncodedSignature().getBytes()));

       System.out.println(SNAPSHOT_API_PATH + payload + "&signature=" + signed);
```

JJWT - This lib generates big signature then the signature generated in node module.

```
String signed = new String(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(Jwts.builder().setPayload(payload)
                .signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, key).compact().getBytes()));

        System.out.println(SNAPSHOT_API_PATH + payload + "&signature=" + signed);
```

sample output signature

```
compactProducer.getEncodedSignature() signed --> qQ5G9_lwGJ9w158FVSmtPx_iH43xlg2_gx9BlHEJbER73xpAeIHtDRnT8wnveH_UEPxNe7Zgv4csJ48Oiq-ZIQ

Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(signature) --> cVE1RzlfbHdHSjl3MTU4RlZTbXRQeF9pSDQzeGxnMl9neDlCbEhFSmJFUjczeHBBZUlIdERSblQ4d252ZUhfVUVQeE5lN1pndjRjc0o0OE9pcS1aSVE

JJWT signed -> ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpGVXpJMU5pSjkuTDJGd2FTOTJNUzl6Ym1Gd2MyaHZkRDlqWlc1MFpYSTlRM1Z3WlhKMGFXNXZMRlZUUVNaMFpXRnRTV1E5V0ZaWU5GWlhSbEZUTXlaclpYbEpaRDFWUVRWTlNGWlhWMWhMLlExUEtoeGwzSjFoVWVUWGtmeXRLckliYm5zeDdZem5lZVpxTVc4WkJOVU9uLVlYeFhyTExVU05ZVTZCSG5Xc3FheFd3YVB5dlF0Yml4TVBSZGdjamJ3
```

Comment: can you share how signature looks like in apache cxf and how big is the byte array of it? Also in your second case I assume that library generates whole JWS so the signature part is located after the second dot.

Comment: compactProducer.getEncodedSignature() signed --> qQ5G9_lwGJ9w158FVSmtPx_iH43xlg2_gx9BlHEJbER73xpAeIHtDRnT8wnveH_UEPxNe7Zgv4csJ48Oiq-ZIQ
Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe(signature) --> cVE1RzlfbHdHSjl3MTU4RlZTbXRQeF9pSDQzeGxnMl9neDlCbEhFSmJFUjczeHBBZUlIdERSblQ4d252ZUhfVUVQeE5lN1pndjRjc0o0OE9pcS1aSVE
JJWT signed -> ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpGVXpJMU5pSjkuTDJGd2FTOTJNUzl6Ym1Gd2MyaHZkRDlqWlc1MFpYSTlRM1Z3WlhKMGFXNXZMRlZUUVNaMFpXRnRTV1E5V0ZaWU5GWlhSbEZUTXlaclpYbEpaRDFWUVRWTlNGWlhWMWhMLlExUEtoeGwzSjFoVWVUWGtmeXRLckliYm5zeDdZem5lZVpxTVc4WkJOVU9uLVlYeFhyTExVU05ZVTZCSG5Xc3FheFd3YVB5dlF0Yml4TVBSZGdjamJ3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signature in the NodeJS code is generated by the `jwa('ES256')#sign` method, which has the following functionality:

1. ES256: ECDSA using P-256 curve and SHA-256 hash algorithm [[1]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwa).
2. The signature will be the pair (r, s), where r and s are 256-bit unsigned integers [[2]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.4).
3. The signature is base64url-encoded [[3]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwa#jwasigninput-secretorprivatekey).

Ad 1: A corresponding implementation for ES256 is possible in Java using on-board means (SunEC provider, Java 1.7 or higher), [[4]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC):

```
Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
ecdsa.initSign(privateKey);     
String payload = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
ecdsa.update(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] signatureDER = ecdsa.sign();
```

Here `privateKey` is the private key of type `java.security.PrivateKey`, analogous to `key` in the CXF code.

Ad 2: The Java code returns the signature in the ASN.1 DER format and must therefore be converted into the (r,s) format [[5]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57731). Either a user-defined method can be implemented or a method from a supporting library can be used, e.g. the method `com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.impl.ECDSA.transcodeSignatureToConcat` of the Nimbus JOSE + JWT library [[6]](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/latest/com/nimbusds/jose/crypto/impl/ECDSA.html#transcodeSignatureToConcat-byte:A-int-)[[7]](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/wiki/Home)[[8]](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/master/src/main/java/com/nimbusds/jose/crypto/impl/ECDSA.java):

```
byte[] signature = transcodeSignatureToConcat(signatureDER, 64);
```

Ad 3: Base64url encoding is possible in Java with on-board means [[9]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder()):

```
String signatureBase64url = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(signature);
```

Since a different signature is generated each time, a direct comparison of the signatures generated in both codes isn't possible. However, compatibility with the jwa-npm library can be tested by verifying the signature generated in the Java code with the jwa-npm library:

```
const jwa = require("jwa");
const ecdsa = jwa('ES256');

var message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var verify = ecdsa.verify(message, signatureBase64url, publicKey);
```

Here, `signatureBase64url` is the signature generated with the Java code. `publicKey` is the corresponding public key in X.509 PEM format (`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----...`) [[10]](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem).

---

The functionality of the `jwa('ES256')#sign` method is *different* from that of the posted JJWT or Apache CXF code: The last two generate a JWT [[11]](https://jwt.io/). The header is the base64url encoding of `{"alg": "ES256"}`. Accordingly the signature is that for the Base64url encoded header and the Base64url encoded payload, both separated by a dot:

```
String payload = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

//JJWT
String jwtJJWT = Jwts.builder().setPayload(payload).signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, privateKey).compact();

//CXF
JwsCompactProducer compactProducer = new JwsCompactProducer(payload);
compactProducer.getJwsHeaders().setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256);
String jwtCXF = compactProducer.signWith(privateKey);
String signatureCXF = compactProducer.getEncodedSignature(); // signature, 3. portion of JWT
```

Example for a JWT generated by this:

```
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZw.rcrzqr3ovu7SH9ci-S6deLn6BuiQkNv9CmeOnUPwva30pfK9BOX0YOgjZP5T08wjxCBTTHV3aex0M76toL8qpw
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @Topaco, its working now.